# Login form is not posting

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm developing a Laravel app, and have setup a login page, but I'm trying to figure out why my login form isn't posting.

```xml
  <form role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('login.perform') }}">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-control-label">Email address</label>
      @if ($errors->has('username'))
        <span class="text-danger text-left">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>
      @endif
      <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="input-email" placeholder="name@example.com">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <div>
          <label class="form-control-label">Password</label>
          @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="text-danger text-left">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
          @endif
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2">
          <a href="#!" class="small text-muted text-underline--dashed border-primary">Lost password?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="input-password" placeholder="Password">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="password-text" data-target="#input-password">
              <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-icon rounded-pill">
        <span class="btn-inner--text">Sign in</span>
        <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

This is the controller that handles the login request.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display login page.
     * 
     * @return Renderable
     */
    public function show()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle account login request
     * 
     * @param LoginRequest $request
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->getCredentials();

        if(!Auth::validate($credentials)):
            return redirect()->to('login')
                ->withErrors(trans('auth.failed'));
        endif;

        $user = Auth::getProvider()->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

        Auth::login($user);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $user);
    }

    /**
     * Handle response after user authenticated
     * 
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Auth $user
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) 
    {
        return redirect()->intended();
    }
}
```

This is the web.php route.

```
<?php
  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
 
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\TeacherController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group that
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
 

Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function()
{   
    /**
     * Home Routes
     */
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@welcome')->name('welcome');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function() {
        /**
         * Register Routes
         */
        Route::get('/register', 'RegisterController@show')->name('register.show');
        Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@register')->name('register.perform');

        /**
         * Login Routes
         */
        Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@show')->name('login.show');
        Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login.perform');

    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
        /**
         * Logout Routes
         */
        Route::get('/logout', 'LogoutController@perform')->name('logout.perform');
    });
});
```

The database is setup, migrated and is appearing in phpMyAdmin, routes controllers and requests are all setup correctly to my understanding.

Any help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-icon rounded-pill">` - **type="submit"**? And  why nest a `<form>` within a `<form>`?

Comment: Hey @Donkarnash, I've changed to submit type, and the page loads after clicking submit but does not send any data to the sql database.

Comment: Please post the code for the controller method which handles `route('login.perform')` - i.e. which handles the form post request. Also remove the nesting of `<form>` - as edited in the question

Comment: LoginController added. I've removed the nesting off my login.blade.php file.

Comment: you are writing what `Auth::attempt` does already

Comment: So this is a login request, only interaction with database from the controller method is to retrieve a user record with email & password values received via email if it exists or throw validation error. Can't understand what you mean by "does not sent any data to sql database" here. Does submitting form with valid email and password login the user or not?

Comment: My mistake, I realised what I've done wrong. Looks to be working now, will do some testing and confirm. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the form can't submit is that you don't have **submit button**, add the `type="submit"` to the `<button>` will resolve the issue:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-icon rounded-pill">
```

I read the comments, and you said the **form is loaded but does not send any data**. Please show how you get data in the controller, and the route also, that will help another find out the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've added that in, and attached the web.php route.

Comment: @MichaelT can you add `LoginRequest` too?

Comment: @MichaelT Add validation message code in the form and check if It catches something?


`@foreach($errors->all() as $error)  <div> {{$error}} </div>  @endforeach`

Comment: I wanna see the `getCredentials()` func in `LoginRequest`, may be find out something wrong in that.

Answer (score 0):

csrf is missing in your form

Try this

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('login.perform') }}">
    @csrf

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the form can't submit is that you don't have submit button, add the type="submit" to the  will resolve the issue:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-icon rounded-pill">
```

and csrf is missing in your form

Try this

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('login.perform') }}">
@csrf

...
```